# XMLHttpRequest : Not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.mobi/. Origin http://www.example.mobi is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How is it possible to have same origin error on two domains that are the same?

Comment: I think that  the key to this is lack of www :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the url is different, www is considered a default subdomain under your app and when you request http://example.mobi it is assumed to be a different url.. You should use relative urls and let the browser query the right url..

hope that helps..